# zurb foundation 5 top bar with asp net mvc 4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, zurb-foundation

I work on an asp net mvc 4 solution working (well) with Zurb foundation 4.
I have to update it to the version 5 of the framework (the current version offers by Zurb is 5.3).
No problem for the moment^^.

But I have an issue with the top bar element with this new version (and the same with sub-nav).
The top-bar appears on my page but the dropdown lists don't work, in full screen as in responsive.

I already check some topics on it and add the "famous" data-topbar on the nav class="top-bar" but it still doesn't work.

I suspect that we won't make the upgrade on the solution if i can't fixed this problem, so I cracked on it for many hours...

Here is a sample of my HTML:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
            <ul class="title-area">
                <!-- Title Area -->
                <li class="name">
                    <h1><a href="@ViewUtils.GetBaseUrlSiteWeb()"><i class="general foundicon-home"></i>TDB </a></h1>
                </li>
                <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
                <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
            </ul>

            <section class="top-bar-section">
                <!-- Left Nav Section -->
                <ul class="left">

                      @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && (! ViewUtils.UtilisateurCourant.IsInfi()))
                      {

                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li class="@classMandats"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Mandat", new {area = "Coach", isMandatSigne = true})">Mandats</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li class="@classContacts"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Mandat", new {area = "Coach", isMandatSigne = false})">Contacts</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>

                      }

                    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && (ViewUtils.UtilisateurCourant.IsSuperAdmin() || ViewUtils.UtilisateurCourant.IsAdmin()))
                    {

                        <li class="@classAdmin"><a href="#">Administration</a>


                            <ul class="dropdown">
                                @*<li><label>Actions</label></li>*@
                                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Utilisateurs", new { area = "Admin" })">@*<img src="~/Areas/Admin/Content/Utilisateurs/icons/group.png" class="MenuIcon" />*@Utilisateurs</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">@*<img src="~/Areas/Admin/Content/Utilisateurs/icons/services.png" class="MenuIcon" />*@Prospect / Client</a>

                                    <ul class="dropdown">
                                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "StatutsClient", new { area = "Admin" })">Statuts</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "RaisonPerte", new { area = "Admin" })">Perte</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "OrigineMandat", new { area = "Admin" })">Origines</a></li>


                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ImmoInverse", new { area = "Admin" })">Import prospects ImmoInversé</a></li>

                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                @{
                                    //string urlProspectsClient = string.Concat(ViewUtils.GetBaseUrlSiteWeb(), "/Areas/Admin/Content/ReportingService/RapportV2.aspx?rapport=1");
                                    string urlProspectsClient = Url.Action("Index", "MarketingStats", new {area = "Admin"});
                                }

                                <li><a href="@urlProspectsClient" target="_blank">Rapp. Prospects/Clients</a></li>
                                @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && ViewUtils.UtilisateurCourant.IsSuperAdmin())
                                {
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Moteur", new { area = "Admin" })">Moteur</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "CleanDataBase", new { area = "Admin" })">Nettoyage de la base de données</a></li>
                                }

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>

                    }
```

If someone can help me it will be nice.

Comment: I forgot to notice that i initialize foundation with <script>$(document).foundation();</script>

Comment: and the @classAdmin is a concatened string for has-dropdown and active